# Gatling response time logging

Tags: logging, gatling, response-time

Is there a way to log details of request which took longer to respond than the values configured in the assertion. I am looking to debug these requests. It will be helpful to have this additional information. I am using scala.

I tried to log responseTime but looks like responseTime is not recognized.